# Feedforward Deep neural networks

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

Hello everyone can you help me to create a diagram for these F-DNN

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn import metrics
num_labels=y.shape[1]
num_labels=y.shape[1]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(40,)))  
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))  
model.build()
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'],optimizer='adam')
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from datetime import datetime 

num_epochs = 100
num_batch_size = 32

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model/pet_bark_classification.h5', 
                               verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

start = datetime.now()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=num_batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[checkpointer], verbose=1)


duration = datetime.now() - start
print("Training completed in time: ", duration)
test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy[1] * 100:.2f}%")
prediction_feature = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])

shape = prediction_feature.shape
X_test[1]
print(shape)
predicted_probabilities = model.predict(X_test)

predicted_classes = np.argmax(predicted_probabilities, axis=1)
```

Comment: Have you tried plot_model() from keras.utils?